# How to download a large S3 file with AWS Lambda (javascript)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have been struggling to get the following code to work properly.   I am using the serverless framework and it works beautifully when invoked locally.   I have a whole workflow where I take the downloaded file and process it before uploading back to S3.  Ideally I would like to process line-by-line, but small steps first!

I can download a small file from S3 with no problems, but the file I am handling is much larger and shouldn't be in memory.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = async function (event, context, callback) {
  let destWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/a.csv");

  let s3Input = { Bucket : "somebucket", Key : "somekey.csv" };
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let s3Stream = S3.getObject(s3Input)
      .createReadStream()
      .on("close", function() {
        resolve("/tmp/a.csv");
      })
      .pipe( destWriteStream );

  }).then(d => {
    console.log(d);
  });

  callback( null, "good" );
};
```

I have tried many different ways of doing this, including Promise's. I am running Node 8.10.  It is just not working when run as a Lambda.  It simply times out.

My issue is that I see very little complete examples.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks for multipart upload in s3.

Comment: Sorry, you meant within lambda and download not upload. What is the size of file? /tmp/ inside Lambda has a size limit too. I would check that size against your file size.

Comment: Thanks johnny .. the file size isn't going to be a problem with the /tmp/ temp storage.  Like i noted, this is a journey, ultimately i want to get to the point where i am processing it line-by-line without it going to temp at all.

Comment: What is your Lambda function timeout set to?

Comment: That is not the problem -- i set that to 5 mins just to rule it out.  The size of file sitting on S3 is only 2MB.

Comment: What is destPath? Appears to be undefined, presumably causing script error so resolve is never called.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod ... ignore that, i updated the code. i had to make it public safe before posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working.  Lambda, really does not do a good job with some of its error reporting.

The issue was that the bucket I was downloading from was from a different region than the Lambda was hosted in.   Apparently this does not make a difference when running it locally.

So ... for others that may tread here ... check your bucket locations relative to your Lambda region.

Comment: You can init your aws sdk/ s3 client with the region of your bucket, see the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html) . It is likely that your local config has the same region as the bucket, while the lambda is in a different one? Setting the region on your client will allow you to use a lambda in a different region from your bucket. However if you intend to pull down larger files you will get network latency benefits from keeping your lambda in the same region as your bucket.

Comment: You indicated earlier that it timed out, not that it returned an error. Did it return an error? If so, what was the error? Also, when responding to individuals in comments, please alert them by including @username in your response, otherwise they will not be notified and you will risk them missing your responses.

Comment: Your basic Lambda function works fine for me when it's hosted in one region (us-east-1) and either reading objects in the same region (us-east-1) or reading objects in a different region (us-west-2). So your problem may lie elsewhere, possibly related to the serverless framework.